# how to pass a value then refresh table using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, yii

now, i work on yii. i used chtml dropdown to show year, when i choose 2015, i want generate table on 2015. and when i choose 2016, will show 2016 table. here is my chtml dropdown code :

```
<?php
echo "Periode Tahun : ".CHtml::dropDownList('list_period_active', $id_periode,$list_period_active);
?>
```

and here is my javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $('#list_period_active').change(function (){

     /*
     $.fn.yiiGridView.update('penilaian-ptsp-periode-grid', {
            data: {'period':$('#list_period_active').val()}
        });
    */


    $('#box-table-a').load( { document.URL +  ' #box-table-a',
            data: {'period':$('#list_period_active').val()}
            });


        return false;
    });

</script>
```

note :above script doesnt work and dont show an error

Comment: most likely you should wrap your binding into a jQuery document ready: 
`$(function () {/* here your code  */ })`

Comment: watch out... the load call can't work, you pass an object literal to it  but the first element is simply a string instead the re should be only 
key : values
elements... start using a good indentation, that could help You

Comment: looking at the [jQuery load doc](http://api.jquery.com/load/) maybe you should write:
`$('#box-table-a').load(document.URL +  ' #box-table-a',{period:$('#list_period_active').val()});`
but I would not bet on it